# I have a question about the declaration of a variable in an object

Tags: javascript, object

When creating an object using Object.create() or a constructor function,

I am curious about using **var** to declare an instance.

first. MDN

```js
// Shape - 상위클래스
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// 상위클래스 메서드
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - 하위클래스
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // super 생성자 호출.
}

// 하위클래스는 상위클래스를 확장
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

second, other blog

```js
var person = Object.create(prototypeObject, {
      'firstName': {
    value: "a", 
    writable: true, 
    enumerable: true
      },
      'lastName': {
    value: "b",
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
      }
```

**var** is a function unit scope, and we know that a problem occurs when the variable names outside the function and inside the function are the same.

So I know that I mainly use **let** and **const** added in ES6.

When instantiating in mdn or in other blogs, var is used

I wonder if it is often used in object-oriented grammar in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking whether `var` declaration is used in javascript very often or not. If it's so, the answer is **NO**. People stopped using it at all since ES6 came out. You'll not find it in modern code but it still can be spot in very old sources which weren't rewritten.

Comment: Thank you. As I studied JS, object-oriented or instance
I often see var in the statement I create. So I was a bit confused, but I understood that since ES6 only let and const are used.

Comment: same way you can ditch `var` these days, you can also start using `class` and avoid ugly, and not always correct, prototype runtime changes.